# How to return array in c?

Tags: c

How to return array in C?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()

    {
        int func(int);
        printf("%d",func(1));

    }

    int func(int n)
    {
        int i,arr[5]; //or int *arr=(int*)malloc(5);
        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            arr[i]=n++;
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

I want to get result '11111', but this code's result is '1606416336'.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't return a local array in C. You need to allocate it dynamically with `malloc()`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm

Comment: https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html

Comment: You can't *ever* return an array in C. It's an annoying limitation. You can, however, return a struct that contains an array, or have the caller create an array and pass a pointer to it as an argument.

Comment: `int func(int n)
{
    int i, v = 0;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        v = v * 10 + n;
    }
    return v;
}`

Comment: Robert Harvey// Wow!!Thanks very much!! It can be help me a lot!!

Comment: immibis// Oh..... Thanks!!! That's the problem!!!

Comment: BLUEPIXY// Thanks to your answer!! That help me a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *func1(int);
    int func2(int);
    int *p = func1(1);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 5; ++i){
        printf("%d", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(p);

    printf("%d",func2(1));
    return 0;
}

int *func1(int n){
    int i;
    int *arr=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        arr[i]=n;
    }
    return arr;
}

int func2(int n){
    int i, v = 0;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        v = v * 10 + n;
    }
    return v;
}
```